# Atomic counter std::memory_order

Tags: c++, c++20, atomic, memory-barriers

I know this has been asked many times before. I have read and watched many of them but still can't fully understand how to properly use memory order types on atomic variables. I want to wait with an atomic counter and a condition variable on detached threads. How each atomic operation should be written?

```cpp
#include <random>
#include <thread>
#include <condition_variable>

int blockAndGet(int a, int b);

int main()
{
    std::jthread producer{[](std::stop_token st)
    {
        std::mutex m;
        std::condition_variable cond;
        std::atomic<std::uint16_t> counter;

        while (!st.stop_requested()) {
            // Get some data to handle(sometimes slower, generally faster than handling it)
            int data = blockAndGet(1, 40);

            // #1 - I'm not interested with the result, are workers too?
            counter.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order::relaxed);

            std::thread{[&](std::stop_token st, int data)
            {
                blockAndGet(30, 100); // Do some work

                if (!st.stop_requested())
                    // #2 - I'm not interested with the result too but do other workers care about?
                    counter.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order::release);
                else {
                    std::lock_guard l{m};
                    // #3 - If I'm the one who has to signal the producer to wake up I had to get the newest value.
                    if (counter.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order::acq_rel) == 1)
                        cond.notify_one();
                }    
            }, st, data}
            .detach();
        }

        std::unique_lock lock{m};
        // #4 I must be sure all workers finished their execution
        cond.wait(lock, [&]{ return counter.load(std::memory_order::acquire) == 0; });
    }};

    // Should spawn ~100 worker thread before stop signal
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds{2});
    return 0;
}

int blockAndGet(int a, int b) {
    // You know what this is intended for
    // No need to think about the random_device's surprises within the scope of this question
    thread_local std::mt19937 engine(std::random_device{}());
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> dist{a, b};
    int val{dist(engine)};
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds{val});
    return val;
}
```

https://godbolt.org/z/f46YMcPTj

I wrote my thoughts in comments. Can you see any potential bug or improvements?

**EDIT1**:

It seems the abstraction that I made got confused people and caused distraction. I'm sorry about that. You can think it as a server program. First blockAndGet is just an accept() system call and returning a file descriptor. With that integer a new thread gets created and client will be handled in it(second blockAndGet). When it is done, if stop not requested thread counter is decremented. If stop requested then producer(listener) will be waiting for all workers to finish and it means also last one of worker threads is responsible to wake up the producer additionaly.

I don't want listener thread to do busy waiting this is why there is condition_variable and mutex. I'm suspicious about atomic::wait does that.

In this example stop signal comes from jthread's destructor at the end of main() function. But it will likely come from another thread(like a manager that serves  only to privileged admin on some port and custom protocol).

Of course this can be implemented with easier ways but I thought it would be a good case to utilize that feature of c++.

I hope this context helps you to realize the problem. Thanks for your time and responses.

**EDIT2**:

With [Nate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74834836/atomic-counter-stdmemory-order#comment132072335_74834836)'s suggestion i changed it as below.

```cpp
    std::jthread producer{[](std::stop_token st)
    {
        std::atomic<std::uint16_t> counter;
        while (!st.stop_requested()) {
            int fd = blockAndGet(1, 40); // accept()
            counter.fetch_add(1, std::memory_order::release); // #1

            std::thread{[&](std::stop_token st, int fd)
            {
                blockAndGet(30, 100); // Do some work with fd

                if (!st.stop_requested())
                    counter.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order::release); // #2
                else if (counter.fetch_sub(1, std::memory_order::acq_rel) == 1) // #3
                    counter.notify_one(); 
            }, st, fd}
            .detach();
        }
        // #4
        for (std::uint16_t old;
                (old = counter.load(std::memory_order::acquire));
                counter.wait(old, std::memory_order::acquire));
    }};
```

Comment: If you use `condition_variable`, you have to use `mutex`. If you use `mutex`, I do not see a reason to use `atomic`, all access is already synchronized. Why do you want `atomic`?

Comment: mutex is needed only when producer wants to wait for workers, not to synchronize accesses on the counter. I think mutex is heavier for counter than it needs to.

Comment: The rule of thumb for `memory_order` is use the default. That just works. To specify it explicitly, you both need to understand what it means *exactly*, and how that works with the underlying hardware. The options are there for experts building libraries. If you are not one of the experts, don't touch it.

Comment: Thanks for your responses but can we think it as I want to be an expert or I am a library writer and need this deepest corner of c++. Don't get me wrong but "don't touch" approach gives no chance to learn.

Comment: Are you aware of [`std::atomic<T>::wait`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic/wait)?  That's the intended substitute for condition variables when working directly with atomics.

Comment: It's hard to analyze this example, because normally the producer would be writing some data that the worker would actually read.  But here they are not actually sharing anything, so it becomes harder to see the need for memory ordering.  For instance, if `blockAndGet` in the producer was to write data for a worker, then the subsequent `counter.fetch_add()` needs to be release at a minimum, otherwise the worker might see an incomplete view of the data.

Comment: The other thing we don't see here is the mechanism for actually assigning work to workers, so that every piece of work is handled by exactly one worker.  Those mechanisms would require their own synchronization which would probably take the place of your simple counter.

Comment: `std::atomic::wait` doesn't busy-wait, try it and see. The whole point of it is to make the thread go to sleep (not consuming CPU) until notified.  It's meant to be a primitive that you could use to implement condition variables and the like.

Comment: Why are you dealing with a `condition_variable` in the first place?

Answer (score 0):

[TLDR](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/memory_order) (if your going to program RCU you need to read the standard).

This requires understanding of cache coherence, CPU memory access ordering,  out-of-order execution and speculative execution, otherwise just keep to seq_cst, or maybe relax if its just counting stuff.

Relax - just work like you would think it all memory operations should work, so if you count to 10000 in different threads it will eventually count up to 10000 and not 9996 like my test without atomic did.

Acquire - release, do stuff after acquire and stop when we do release. We are sure we have a value when we start our calculation, and update to others when we finish.

acq_rel - we finish all mem access before and then do our stuff and then the next stuff can happen.

seq_cst - we finish all mem access before and then do our stuff and then the next stuff can happen and we have total ordering. This is very nice if you want to insure correctness and not really think about it, but is somewhat slow (very on some architectures).

consume - we don't have a total memory order, so the compiler needs to help us here (Arm, Itanium, PowerPC and Alpha I think). Most compilers just think ... lets give them a seq_cst and they will be served.

Why all this stuff? (from memory so take this with a spoonful of salt)

- Dec Alpha: cache coherency and memory ordering only when requested ...
- PowerPC: You know what your doing right? so that perfect memory ordering is not needed, just require it when needed OK?
- Arm: Oh I got more cores I'd better make some consistency, we will fix everything in Arm8 using C++11's definitions!!!
- x86 - our users are expecting us to help them not shoot themselves in the foot so we mandate a total ordering!!! you want to shoot yourself in the foot? lets add some instructions to do that!!!

Ordered in the way that theoretically makes the fastest execution to slowest, but also how difficult it is to maintain correctness. If you don't make cache coherency checks on every write you might be somewhat faster and get more interesting results ...

If we didn't have these we would need to know how the compiler and CPU reordered all memory access and all the extra instructions we would need for each CPU.